# How to prevent the code from running if error is displayed?

Tags: c++

When I ask the user to input a value and the value is not allowed to be there, I want the program to end instead of keep on going. I tried to use a break; but it doesn't work with an if statement. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
int main(){ 
    int flips, guess;

    cout << "How " << endl;
    cin >> flips;

    cout << "Guess  " << endl;
    cin >> guess;
    if(guess>flips) {
        cout << "Guess Error" << endl;
    }
}
```

The code gives out "Guess Error" when an invalid input is placed but the rest of the code also runs.

Comment: What if the user enters a string that isn't a number? I recommend factoring the logic of "read user input" and then re-use that both for `flips` and `guess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should validate the input of `flips` and `guess`. If the input is not an integer value the input expression will return false.

```
if(!(cin >> flips))
{
    cout << "Input must be an integer" << endl;
    return 1; // return from main with error code
}
```

The same should be applied to validate the input of `flips`. If the number of guesses is greater than the number of flips just return...

```
if (guess > flip)
{
    cout << "Guess Error" << endl;
    return 2; // return with error code 2
}
```

Note that the error values used in the return statements are arbitrary and can be replaced to match your exact requirements.

Comment: Would probably be better to use `EXIT_FAILURE`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status